# RAM disk in macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, mac, storage, ventura

How to create a [RAM drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive) in [macOS Ventura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura)?

---

The Apple App Store lists only a single app for creating a RAM disk. And apparently that app does not actually work, per review comments.

---

For the curious… Reasons to use a RAM disk include:

- Avoid needlessly wearing out storage device, whether [solid-state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_storage) or [spinning-rust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive).
- Avoid polluting a continuous [back-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup_software) mechanism, such as [Time Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_(macOS)) on [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS), with multiple copies of rewritten files that we'll never need.
- Avoid delays waiting for writes-to-storage to complete. [RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) is *much* faster than storage, even solid-state storage.

These problems are more acute for people developing and/or testing software.

Modern [file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) perform smart caching in RAM. However, this does not mitigate the problems in the above bullet-list.

Comment: This question has come up before, just searching for „RAM disk“ on AD lists several Q&A with the relevant command (as does searching for „create RAM disk on macOS“ in the wider web).

Comment: I'm curious what the use case is for RAM disks, now that file data is cached in RAM and SSDs are so much faster these days. I'm not convinced by the examples given in the linked article, on an M-series Mac.

Comment: @benwiggy Use case: Files being repeatedly rewritten that don’t need to be persisted to real storage. Such writing slows down my work. These frequent rewrites are common in software development & testing work, in scientific data analysis, etc. Caching files in RAM benefits only  file *reads*, not writes. And SSDs are fast, but not as fast as RAM. Also, writing to SSDs wears them out, so best to avoid needless writes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution works for me on Ventura 13.4.1. Taken from an article by [Tom Nelson](https://eshop.macsales.com/blog/author/tom-n/) on the MacSales.com site, [*How to Create and Use a RAM Disk with Your Mac (Warnings Included!)*](https://eshop.macsales.com/blog/46348-how-to-create-and-use-a-ram-disk-with-your-mac-warnings-included/).

In a terminal app, run:

```bash
diskutil erasevolume HFS+ "RAMDisk" `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://2048`
```

- `"RAMDisk"` is the name of the volume.
- `2048` is the number of blocks of memory to be assigned to your RAM drive.

Specify 2048 per meg of memory you want assigned to your RAM drive.

| Drive size | Argument | Math |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 MB | **2048** | = 1 MB * 2048 |
| 256 MB | **524288** | = 256 MB * 2048 |
| 512 MB | **1048576** | = 512 MB * 2048 |
| 1 GB | **2097152** | = 1024 MB * 2048 |
| 2 GB | **4194304** | = 2048 MB * 2048 |

Beware: Your data on the RAM drive is destroyed upon a crash or restart of the Mac.

For more info, see the `man` pages:

```bash
man diskutil
```

… and:

```bash
man hdiutil
```

Be careful in choosing a size. The `man` page says that when using the `com_apple_hdid_kernel` environment variable, “WARNING: `ram://` images use wired memory when attached in-kernel.”

Comment: `man hdiutil`also describes this, with an example including mounting the RAM disk.

Comment: Is the RAM drive created in permanent memory (wired) or is it subject to paging (compression and swap)?

Comment: @Gilby The `man` page says that when using the `com_apple_hdid_kernel` environment variable, “WARNING: ram:// images use wired memory when attached in-kernel.”